# Make a Grid from a string in a text file

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have three run arguments that are min width, max width and the text file name. The text files are filled with one long string of random characters. I want to put each character into a grid spot. But all I get back is the string itself from the file. How do I make the grid?

```
class GridCipher{

   static int minGridWidth;
   static int maxGridWidth;

   static File inputFile;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      if (handleArguments(args))
      processInput();

   }

   static final String usage = "Usage: GridWriter min_width max_width input_file_name";

   static boolean handleArguments(String[] args) {
      // Check for correct number of arguments
      if (args.length != 3) {
         System.out.println("Wrong number of command line arguments.");
         System.out.println(usage);
         return false;
      }

   try {
         minGridWidth = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
         maxGridWidth = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
         System.out.println("min_width and max_width must be integers.");
         System.out.println(usage);
         return false;
      }

      inputFile = new File(args[2]);
      if (!inputFile.canRead()) {
         System.out.println("The file " + args[2] + " cannot be opened for input.");
         return false;
      }

      return true;
   }

   static void processInput() throws FileNotFoundException {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
      String line = input.nextLine();
      int length = line.length(); // number of characters.

   // Try each width in the appropriate range
      for (int width = minGridWidth; width <= maxGridWidth; width++) {
         // Determine heigth of grid
         int height = line.length() / width;

         // Add one to height if there's a partial last row
         if (line.length() % width != 0)
            height += 1;

         loadUnloadGrid(line, width, height);
      }
  }

   static void loadUnloadGrid(String line, int width, int height) {
      char grid[][] = new char[height][width];

      // Determine number long columns
      int longColumn = line.length() % width;
      if (longColumn == 0)
         longColumn = width;

      //Load the input data into the grid by column
      int charCount = 0;
      for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
         for (int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
            if (r < height - 1 || c < longColumn) {
               grid[r][c] = line.charAt(charCount);
               charCount += 1;
            }
         }
      }

      // Output data from the grid by rows
      for (int r = 0; r < height - 1; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
            System.out.print(grid[r][c]);
         }
      }
      // Special handling for last row
      for (int c = 0; c < longColumn; c++) {
         System.out.print(grid[height - 1][c]);
      }
      System.out.println("\"");  
   }
}
```

If the text file has ABCDE, I just get back ABCDE. I would like the characters in a grid determined by my min and max width.

Comment: Could you explain for people like me what do you mean characters in a gird determined by my min and max width?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: if I choose width to be 2 then the grid would be AB, CD, E left over with a extra space.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want ABCDEFG into

```
 A B C
 D E F
 G
```

but in the fragment writing it on screen you miss new line character

```
// Output data from the grid by rows
      for (int r = 0; r < height - 1; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
            System.out.print(grid[r][c]);
         }
      }
```

should be

```
// Output data from the grid by rows
      for (int r = 0; r < height - 1; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
            System.out.print(grid[r][c]);
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing grid is not correct in your program.

Change below to

```
// Output data from the grid by rows
for (int r = 0; r < height - 1; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
        System.out.print(grid[r][c]);
    }
}
```

this code

```
for(char[] arr : grid) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```